# SQLite not Returning all Records from a Table - SQLite-JDB

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I have a very large table (1074 records), and I am trying to access it with the following query:

```
PreparedStatement queryColumn = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('ImportedCSV')");
ResultSet columns = queryColumn.executeQuery();
```

While this works, it will only return a certain number of these records. I want to get all of them.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO()` returns 1 row for each column of the table with columns like the name and the type of the column. It does not return the rows of the table.

Comment: I miscommunicated. I want all of them and the SQLite Java Library won't give them to me.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below query

`SELECT * FROM  sqlite_master`

then fetch all the table detail sequentially

`for(String tableName: tableNameList){ PreparedStatement queryColumn = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('+tableName+')"); ResultSet columns = queryColumn.executeQuery(); }`

Comment: No, I mean all of the records, not all of the tables.

Comment: Read again my answer. or change your question.